# Razor Pages - Client-side Validation Error Message Always Displays

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, razor

In my razor pages app, I have an input field for quantity. To make sure users can't enter anything below 0 or above 99,999, I have validation in place. The validation works. The problem is the error message displays on form submission, even if the value passes validation. It does not display when the page is first loaded, only when the form is submitted. The page is reloaded if an error occurs further down the line (functionality unrelated to this question), and this is when the error message displays incorrectly. The error message disappears if I change the value, but the error message appearing when it shouldn't be will still lead users to incorrectly believe the error was at least partially due to the quantity (when in fact nothing is wrong with it).

```
<td class="col-4">
   <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" asp-for="PartInfo" value="@part.QUANTITY" id="@part.QUANTITY" name="PartInfo" onchange="HighlightField(this)" />
   <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="PartInfo"></span>
</td>
```

```
[DisplayName("Quantity"), BindProperty, Required]
[Range(1, 99999, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number between 1 and 99,999.")]
public List<int> PartInfo { get; set; }
```

[This link shows the input field on the page with the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEg6C.png)

I did look for this answer, but all I found were instances of this happening with ASP MVC and not Razor Pages. The solution did not work here.

It might help to mention that this is what I had at one point, and I had the exact same issue with the error message displaying. It had other problems, which is why I changed it.

```
[DisplayName("Quantity"), BindProperty, Required, MaxLength(5)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\\d+$", ErrorMessage = "The quantity must be a number.")]
public List<int> PartInfo { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

PartInfo is an array that has part ID, part number, and quantity for each part in it, and I iterated through it using a foreach loop to create the input fields for each part.

I had to create separate properties for each element of PartInfo (part ID, part #, and quantity), and change the name attribute to point to those properties.

```
[DisplayName("Part ID"), BindProperty, Required]
[Range(1, 999999999, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number between 1 and 999,999,999.")]
public int PartID { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Part Number"), BindProperty, Required]
[StringLength(48, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a part number.")]
public string PartNumber { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Quantity"), BindProperty, Required]
[Range(1, 99999, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number between 1 and 99,999.")]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

```
@foreach (var part in Model.PartInfoList)
{
<tr class="row table-bordered">
    <td class="col-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" asp-for="PartInfo" value="@part.PART_ID" id="@part.PART_ID" **name="PartID"** onchange="HighlightField(this)" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="PartID"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" asp-for="PartInfo" value="@part.PART_NUMBER" id="@part.PART_NUMBER" **name="PartNumber"** onchange="HighlightField(this)" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="PartNumber"></span>
    </td> 
    <td class="col-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" asp-for="PartInfo" value="@part.QUANTITY" id="@part.QUANTITY" **name="Quantity"** onchange="HighlightField(this)" />
        @*The id here is used to determine if the field should be highlighted or not.*@
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Quantity"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```